# copy constructor of an inherited class

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor

I'm trying to define the copy constructor of a class but I'm mistaking. I'm trying to do a son of `QGraphicsRectItem` using this constructor:

```
QGraphicsRectItem( qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0 )
```

here some code

QGraphicsRectItem defined by QtL

```
QGraphicsRectItem( qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0 )
```

Cell.h, son's class:

```
Cell();
Cell(const Cell &c);
Cell(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0 );
```

Cell.cpp:

```
Cell::Cell() {}

/* got error defining this constructor (copy constructor) */
Cell::Cell(const Cell &c) :
    x(c.rect().x()), y(c.rect().y()),
    width(c.rect().width()), height(c.rect().height()), parent(c.parent) {}


Cell::Cell(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem *parent) : 
    QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, width, height, parent) {
    ...
    // some code
    ...
}
```

error says:

```
/../../../../cell.cpp:7: error: class 'Cell' does not have any field named 'x'
/../../../../cell.cpp:7: error: class 'Cell' does not have any field named 'y'
/../../../../cell.cpp:7: error: class 'Cell' does not have any field named 'width'
/../../../../cell.cpp:7: error: class 'Cell' does not have any field named 'height'
/../../../../cell.cpp:7: error: class 'Cell' does not have any field named 'parent'
```

thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're actually inheriting from the right parentclass?

Comment: what else is on the line that says `class Cell` ?

Comment: this solve it: Cell::Cell(const Cell &c) : QGraphicsRectItem( c.rect().x(), c.rect().y(), c.rect().width(), c.rect().height()) {} does somebody knows why? (is been a long time i don't se my dear C++)

Comment: You are now calling a constructor of the base class from your copy constructor

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your copy constructor as follows:

```
Cell::Cell(const Cell &c)
    :
        QGraphicsRectItem(c.rect().x(), c.rect().y(),
                          c.rect().width(), c.rect().height(),
                          c.parent())
{}
```

The reason is that your `Cell` class **is** a `QGraphicsRectItem` because of inheritance. Thus `c` argument of the constructor is also representing `QGraphicsRectItem`, so you can use its `QGraphicsRectItem::rect()` and `QGraphicsRectItem::parent()` functions to construct new object - the copy of `c`.